# Arrangement of distinct balls with different colors

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume we are arranging 20 distinct balls in a row where 5 are blue and 15 are red.
And let us define the following events:
$A$ = "There are no blue balls in the 5 left-most places of the row"
$B$ = "There is at least one blue ball in the 5 right-most places of the row"

Need to calculate:

1. What is the probability that at least 3 blue balls will be present in the first 10 left-most places of the row?
2. $P(A\cap B)$
3. $P(A^c\cap B)$

For the first calculation I tried doing: $\frac{{5\choose3}{15 \choose 7} + {5\choose4}{15 \choose 6} + {5 \choose 5}{15 \choose 5}}{{20 \choose 10}}$ for choosing 3 blue balls and 7 red balls + 4 blue balls and 6 red + 5 blue balls + 5 red then I divided it by the number of total ways to arrange the 10 elements.

As for the second and the third I got stuck, I tried looking for any reference here in StackExchange but couldn't find anything, I'll be grateful for any insights. thanks

Comment: Well, what is $A\cap B$?  You need no blue in the first $5$, hence all red.  That leave you with $10$ red and $5$ blue for the back $15$.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: @lulu Yes I know how to handle this case but my main problem is that I don't know how to take care of event B, which requires at least one blue ball in the 5 right-most places

Comment: But, I spelled that out.  First you need $A$ to have happened.  So $\binom {15}{5}\big / \binom {20}5$.  That's a multiplicative factor.  Now you need $B$ to also happen *given* that you have $10$ red and $5$ blue left.  Note that the only way $B$ might fail is if all $5$ of the blue ones are in slots $\#6-15$.

Comment: So basically it's ${15 \choose 5} / {20 \choose 5} * (1-{10 \choose 5}/{15 \choose 5})$ ?

Comment: Looks good! $\quad$

Comment: $p(A^c \cap B)~$ analogizes to *cross-breeding* Inclusion-Exclusion with probability.  The desired computation is $$1 - p\left( ~A ~~~\textbf{or}~~~ B^c ~\right) = 1 - p(A) - p(B^c) + p(A,B^c) $$ $$= 1 - 2\left[ ~\frac{\binom{15}{5}}{\binom{20}{5}}  ~\right]  +\left[ ~\frac{\binom{10}{5}}{\binom{20}{5}}  ~\right].$$

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you, I managed to solve that as well !